# How can I use mongoose's "includes"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check my database which contains "likes" field as array type, so I come across this in mongoose documentation but I don't actually know how to use it :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-includes

Here is what I just tried

```
Products.find({_id:uniqueId}, {$includes:{likes:req.user._id}}, function(err, result){......})
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Why are you using `_id: uniqueId` ? If you have an id, you dont need anything else and should use `Products.findById` instead. If you want to search ALL products that include `uniqueId` in an array field then use `Products.find({likes: uniqueId});`. The `includes` you're mentioned is a function that is available on mongoose arrays (the results youre getting)

Comment: Am checking whether the current user has already liked the product, if his Id is saved there in the like array then I want to remove it if it's not then I want to add that's why I want to check whether it exists or not

Comment: I want to use this documentation  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-includes

Comment: That won't work. includes is a function that is present on the results that you get when you query your database. It is NOT something that you use to query...

try `Products.find({_id: productId, likes: userId});`

Comment: You are confusing this by having the same id. Your uniqueId should either be the productId or userId. Right now your query is malformed and even if you get the right structure it is checking for a product with id uniqueId which has uniqueId in likes field.

Comment: Please update question with both the ids. Also, you can simply get your unique product document in JS, and then check for the userId in field right? That will be much easier and faster if your document is not very big.

Answer (score 1):

To your image:

It is complaining because you used `Products.find`. As you are passing in two objects, it expects the second object to be a projection. Projection selects fields from the returned documents to only get only the fields that you need.

Try to get the product with the uniqueId (which I hope is the productId...).

`Product.findById(productId, function (err, result) { // callback })`

Inside the callback you can check if your userId is included in the likes array.